# Disable autocomplete in UIWebView/WKWebview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

Im working on a simple app that acts as a webview. I need to disable auto complete and several other keyboard functions on anything loaded in the webview. I know how to disable autocomplete per UITextInput in a normal view controller but I don't know weather you can disable autocomplete globally on a webview?

I looked at the documentation for UITextInputTraits [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html) but could not seem to make anything work.

A final resort would be to disable autocomplete in the HTML tags but that would require a lot of work on the back end.

Is there a way to disable autocomplete globally for the app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this with iOS code. But, i might be wrong.

You can try running the below JS in the webview every time you load the web page

```
var textFields = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

if (textFields) {
    var i;
    for( i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++) {
        var txtField = textFields[i];
        if(txtField) {
            txtField.setAttribute('autocomplete','off');
            txtField.setAttribute('autocorrect','off');
            txtField.setAttribute('autocapitalize','off');
            txtField.setAttribute('spellcheck','false');
        }
    }
}
```

In my opinion, this should do the job without you having to do the changes in the server :)

Would be interested to know if this worked for you

Comment: not all input tags are textFields, input type can also be file, date/time, email, phone-number, image, radio, checkbox, month, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have searched alot for this issue. If you want to *totally disable* it, then you have to use `<textarea>` instead of `<div contenteditable="true">` and load it in `UIWebview`. Try the below code:

```
 <textarea id="content" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
```

By using this code, **Predictive text and autocomplete** both will *get off*.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using a WKWebView, use this function:

```
func RemoveAutoCompleteFromWebView(webView: WKWebView) {
    let script: String = """
        var textFields = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

        if (textFields) {
            var i;
            for( i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++) {
                var txtField = textFields[i];
                if(txtField) {
                    txtField.setAttribute('autocomplete','off');
                    txtField.setAttribute('autocorrect','off');
                    txtField.setAttribute('autocapitalize','off');
                    txtField.setAttribute('spellcheck','false');
                }
            }
        }
    """
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(script, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

This will run the JavaScript necessary for disabling autocomplete in the new type of WebView. Just pass in the WKWebView that you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
func disableAutocomplete() {
    let disableAutocompleteScript: String = """
        var textFields = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
        if (textFields) {
            var i;
            for( i = 0; i < textFields.length; i++) {
                var txtField = textFields[i];
                if(txtField) {
                    txtField.setAttribute('autocomplete','off');
                    txtField.setAttribute('autocorrect','off');
                    txtField.setAttribute('autocapitalize','off');
                    txtField.setAttribute('spellcheck','false');
                }
            }
        }
    """
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: disableAutocompleteScript)
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.